# Button Component Requires Two Clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shipping form section on my website, and a Button at the end of it, that's supposed to get the values of the form and post this data to my backend server, but whenever I click the first time nothing works, it only works on the second time of clicking.

This is my custom button components

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <Link to={props.buttonLink}>
        <button
          className={`${styles.buttonDefault} ${
            props.display ? '' : styles.hideButton
          } ${props.buttonClass}`}
          onClick={props.onClick}
        >
          {props.buttonText}
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

This is my Button Component used in another jsx file

```
<Button
          buttonClass={styles.buttonClass}
          buttonText="CONFIRM ORDER"
          onClick={onClickShippingButton}
          display
        />
```

This is the code that my button component triggers

```
const onClickShippingButton = () => {
    setButtonClicked(true);

    // Set validated to true
    if (firstName && lastName && email && phoneNumber && locale) {
      setValidated(true);
    }

    if (validated) {
      // If validated is true, send the request to the server, if the server's response is successful load next page, if not then an error page is loaded
      console.log('Performing');
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/orders', {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          phone: phoneNumber,
          locale,
          outsideCanada,
          cart: props.cart.items,
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          // If response is not an error setResponse
          if (res.data.status === 'success') {
            // Set response message to true
            setResponse(true);

            // Reset Cart If Successful
            props.setCart(new Cart());
          } else if (
            res.data.status === 'fail' ||
            res.data.status !== 'success'
          ) {
            console.log(res);
            // Throw error so that it will be caught in the catch block
            // throw new Error(res.data.message);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setResponse(true);
          setError(true);
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: why are you wrapping button inside Link component?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem can be in this place..

```
    if (firstName && lastName && email && phoneNumber && locale) {
      setValidated(true);
    }

    if (validated) {
```

Remember that **setValidator** is an async function and you cannot rely on their value right after calling it. You have two options, either change the if statement or add a useEffect hooks that listens for the confirmed change.

```js
    if (firstName && lastName && email && phoneNumber && locale) {
        setValidated(true);

        // call axios here
    }
```

or

```js
    useEffect( () => { // this function is called only after "validated" state change
        if( validated ) {
             // call axios here
        }
    }, [validated])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you so much! I didn't know that setState functions were asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Button Component` this way, It will fix your double click issue

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <Link to={props.buttonLink} component="button" className={`${styles.buttonDefault} ${
            props.display ? '' : styles.hideButton
          } ${props.buttonClass}`}
          onClick={props.onClick}>
          {props.buttonText}
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```